# Como cambiar un texto dinamicamente en kivy,python desde un hilo

Tags: python, hilos, kivy

Estoy intentando cambiar el texto de una stringProperty desde un hilo pero no se como acceder a la string property desde el hilo
este es el hilo :

```
   def worker():
    dev = InputDevice('/dev/input/by-id/usb-Logitech_USB_Keyboard-event-kbd')
    # Provided as an example taken from my own keyboard attached to a Centos 6 box:
    scancodes = {
        # Scancode: ASCIICode
        0: None, 1: u'ESC', 2: u'1', 3: u'2', 4: u'3', 5: u'4', 6: u'5', 7: u'6', 8: u'7', 9: u'8',
        10: u'9', 11: u'0', 12: u'-', 13: u'=', 14: u'BKSP', 15: u'TAB', 16: u'Q', 17: u'W', 18: u'E', 19: u'R',
        20: u'T', 21: u'Y', 22: u'U', 23: u'I', 24: u'O', 25: u'P', 26: u'[', 27: u']', 28: u'CRLF', 29: u'LCTRL',
        30: u'A', 31: u'S', 32: u'D', 33: u'F', 34: u'G', 35: u'H', 36: u'J', 37: u'K', 38: u'L', 39: u';',
        40: u'"', 41: u'`', 42: u'LSHFT', 43: u'\\', 44: u'Z', 45: u'X', 46: u'C', 47: u'V', 48: u'B', 49: u'N',
        50: u'M', 51: u',', 52: u'.', 53: u'/', 54: u'RSHFT', 56: u'LALT', 100: u'RALT'
    }

    for event in dev.read_loop():
        if event.type == evdev.ecodes.EV_KEY:
            data = evdev.categorize(event)  # Save the event temporarily to introspect it
            if data.keystate == 1:  # Down events only
                key_lookup = scancodes.get(data.scancode) or u'UNKNOWN:{}'.format(data.scancode)  # Lookup or return UNKNOWN:XX
                print(u'You Pressed the {} key!'.format(key_lookup))  # Print it all out!


t = Thread(target=worker)
t.start()
```

este es el codigo donde defino el stringProperty:

```
class Controller(BoxLayout):
random_string = StringProperty("hola")


def do_action(self):
    self.random_string="h22l"
    print(self.random_string)
def do_action2(self):
    self.random_string="hl2332323"
    print(str(self.random_string))
```

La idea seria cambiar el texto despues del print de el hilo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ten siempre en cuenta que toda aquella operación que implique a OpenGL solo debe hacerse desde el hilo principal. Nunca interactúes con los widgets de la interfaz desde otro hilo que no sea el hilo principal directamente, para ello usa el decorador [`@mainthread`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.clock.html#kivy.clock.mainthread)  para que la llamada se haga desde el hilo principal en el siguiente frame.

Un ejemplo con un contador de 0 a 10 implementado en un hilo y que actualiza una `StringProperty` en la app:

```
import threading
import time
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.clock import mainthread



class MainWidget(BoxLayout):
    label_str = StringProperty("")
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.orientation = "vertical"

        self.label = Label(text=self.label_str)
        self.bind(label_str=self.label.setter('text'))
        self.add_widget(self.label)
        self.add_widget(Button(text="Iniciar hilo", on_press=self.iniciar_hilo))

    def iniciar_hilo(self, *args):
        if self.label_str == '':
            t = threading.Thread(target=self.worker)
            t.start()

    def worker(self):
        self.update_label("Iniciando")
        time.sleep(1)
        for n in range(10):
            self.update_label(str(n))
            time.sleep(1)
        self.update_label("Terminado")
        time.sleep(1)
        self.update_label("")

    @mainthread
    def update_label(self, value):
        self.label_str = value



class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainWidget()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Cuando desde el hilo es llamado el método `update_label`, la llamada se lleva a cabo en el hilo principal gracias al decorador `@mainthread`, puedes actualizar un widget directamente de la misma forma.

Comment: Muchas gracias ,lo adapte y me sirvió